# Access SQL Query: Get specific field of a previous record looked up by date

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am pretty new to Access databases and I am trying to create an inventory database for a gas distribution company with multiple gas stations.

Each station has an inventory of more products/gas types.

The gas stations report their inventory including

- TransactionDate
- GallonsSold
- GallonsDelivered
- ActualGallonsInventory
- BookedInventory

The difference between ActualGallonsInventory and BookedInventory is the overage/shortage on gas.

In my query I want to display the stock level (ActualGallonsInventory) of the previous day for the station/gas combination. How can I look up a certain entry of the previous day and display it in my query as a field?

There is only one entry for each station/gas/date combination.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select 
    *, 
        (Select Top 1 ActualGallonsInventory
        From YourTable As T
        Where T.TransactionDate < YourTable.TransactionDate
        Order By T.TransactionDate Desc) As 
    PreviousActualGallonsInventory            
From 
    YourTable
```